# If a prop changes does this change will be accessible via this.props before the component is re-rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

If a prop called this.onUpdate changes on a react component, can this change be available on this.props before the component re-renders?

For an example: 
I have a component Component1 which uses another component Component2 in the following way:

```
class Component1 extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <Component2 onUpdate={this.checkUpdate1} />
        );
    } 
}
```

And Component2 uses the onUpdate prop to send informations to the Component1:

```
class Component2 extends React.Component{
    sendUpdatedInfo = (event) => {
        this.props.onUpdate(event.target.value);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <input onChange={this.sendUpdatedInfo} />
        );
    }
}
```

Supose some information comes from the server via websocket and that makes Component1 change the callback which he is sending to Component2:

```
class Component1 extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <Component2 onUpdate={this.checkUpdate2} />
        );
    } 
}
```

When the user first saw the UI the callback being used is this.checkUpdate1, is there any possibility of the next time when he types the this.props.onUpdate has changed by the UI has not re-rendered?